# Will cooking previously-frozen cream make is less grainy?

Tags: cream, frozen

I bake smoked fish in double cream with a sprinkle of cheese. I have frozen double cream and will use it if the cooking ensures a smooth sauce without a grainy texture. So I am really asking if cooking will smooth the texture.

Comment: Are you saying that the sauce is grainy while warm?  What's grainy, the cheese, the cream, or the bits of fish?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, your problem is that your cream became grainy when thawing.

You won't be able to get that cream smooth, especially not by cooking it. It will stay grainy whatever you do.

A possible use is to "hide" it in a place where grainy dairy is OK. There are cake and savory-flanlike recipes made with slightly grainy cheeses like tvorog in the batter, you can use it there as a substitute. They don#t taste grainy when you bite into them.